# Handling links from iframes in ExtJS

Tags: html, extjs

ExtJS - 2.0.2

I have a html page which uses ExtJs which has an iframe that I created using `Ext.ux.ManagedIFrame`. The iframe loads a web/wiki page and whenever a "link" is clicked in these child pages currently it replaces the whole browser window with the required link. I would like to load all pages opened in the same iframe and not in the browser window.

My child pages are straightforward html pages with "a href" links. Can this be done?

```
Parent Page
    head
    body
        ...
        ...
        iframe id="childiframe" (can't edit anything inside the iframe contents)
            head
            body
                ........
                <a href="www.google.com">Go</a> 
                <!--
                 When you click on the above link rather redirecting the whole 
                 browser to that link. I would just like the childiframe to reload
                 google.com
                 -->
```

Comment: What about the target attribute? `<a href="http://www.google.com" target="framename">Link</a>`

Comment: I need to change the pages included inside the iframe for this. I only have access to the parent page the page that included the element

Comment: I see your problem now.. What about `<base target="_parent" />` in your `<HEAD>` section of the child pages?

Comment: I can't edit the child page. I have now added a picture to my question which will hopefully clarify the question